# What is the service "DEVICES" in azure services?

Tags: azure, cloud

I am getting charged for an **additional service, namely: DEVICES**. I haven`t deployed anything under it on azure portal still getting charged for it along with other services.

```
"per_service_bill" : {
        "Compute" : 1127.4031374062,
        "DEVICES" : 1230.28225806452,
        "Network" : 2208.84024295638,
    },
```

Why am I being charged for this and what is it exactly for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devices refers to the number of hardware devices that is being connected to the azure service that you are using such as **[`IOTHub`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/iot-hub/)**, EventHub, TimeSeriesInsights etc

Comment: does it include all the azure services (compute, networking etc)?

Answer (score 1):

"DEVICES" I believe is related to Azure IoT Hub.

[image]